# Manually install fontconfig, without root, for Java

Tags: java, fontconfig, jenkins

While installing Jenkins on a server without root access, I get the following:

> AWT is not properly configured on this server. Perhaps you need to
> run your container with "-Djava.awt.headless=true

To bypass it, two things must be fixed.

One is to run with `export JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` as an environment variable.

The second is a bit tricker. You need to install "fontconfig" as [per this page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem).

I've tested this on another box where I have root access `sudo apt-get install fontconfig` and it solves the issue. My question is, **how can I manually install `fontconfig` and how to tell `java` where to look for it**.

Comment: Without `root` or without a user who can `sudo` the rights, there's no way to install the font on the machine, so I think you need `root` privileges first, which is inevitable, and why would you want to use `Java` to do that? Just install the font, you don't need to tell Java that he's there after you install it.

Comment: @山河以无恙 my goal is to run Jenkins, and Jenkins needs fonts, otherwise it won’t run. Unfortunately being non-root is also a necessity. But I can’t imagine not being able to drop some font files on the drive and tell Java where they are. I just don’t know how! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system doesn't have fonts installed, and you're running programs which need them, like Jenkins, the best solution is to update `$JAVA_HOME/lib` folder and add a file named `fontconfig.properties`.

You can copy the contents from this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ojdkbuild/tools_bootjdk11/master/lib/fontconfig.properties.src (remember to remove the .src extension when copying).

Then, on relevant entries like:

```
filename.Arial=ARIAL.TTF
filename.Arial_Bold=ARIALBD.TTF
filename.Arial_Italic=ARIALI.TTF
filename.Arial_Bold_Italic=ARIALBI.TTF
```

Just change them to something like

```
filename.Arial=/home/frankie/fonts/Arial.ttf
filename.Arial_Bold=/home/frankie/fonts/ArialBold.ttf
filename.Arial_Italic=/home/frankie/fonts/ArialItalic.ttf
filename.Arial_Bold_Italic=/home/frankie/fonts/ArialBoldItalic.ttf
```

And you're all set!